# Twig template file not recognized

Tags: drupal, twig

I have a page-view that prints "Fields" as "unformatted list". I am trying to name my view after adding the below suggestion on the .theme file:

```
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_views_view_fields_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $view_name = $variables['view']->id();
  $view_display = $variables['view']->current_display;
  if ($view_name && $view_display) {
    $suggestions[] = $variables['theme_hook_original'] . '__' . $view_name . '__' . $view_display;
  }
```

According to the suggestion the twig file is named as : `views_view_field__my_view__page__1.html.twig`

But the template is not getting recognized. View name is my_view. Can someone help on correcting my view twig template name?

Comment: do you return the $suggestions array? Also double check the spelling in the function name MYMODULENAME_theme_suggestions_views_view_field_alter

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the cache and enable debug mode [with this instructions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914).

Besides, you can confirm that your param in the hook is OK:

[image]

Dont forget to rename mytheme for your real name in the function.